# What is this material on my countertops, and how can I remove it?

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters, epoxy

I just purchased a fixer-upper that needs a lot of work. While it's not the peak of my list of current concerns, I'm worried about this material on the countertop. It seems to be some sort of very soft paint (perhaps latex?) over a harder, crunchy black material (perhaps epoxy?) over a laminate wood patterned countertop. The paint comes away easily, but the black material is very hard to remove.
I've had some success using physical scraping with a putty knife and razor blade, but the process is laborious and physically painful. I'm also nervous about potentially scraping the underlying laminate. Replacing the 40-year-old cabinets and countertops is a planned future project, but it won't be one I can prioritize in the next 2 years.

Q: Any suggestions about what this material might be, or advice on how to more easily remove it?[image: photo of countertop and edge of sink. Gray surface has been scraped away to reveal a black material and wood texture below]

Comment: At a glance, that looks like someone started to refinish the counters by removing their laminate, but never got around to scraping off the black adhesive and putting a new surface into the counter. Especially since you said this was a fixer-upper; often those are houses that people started to renovated and then discovered it was a bigger task than they expected.

Comment: consider a stone coat or other epoxy finish; can be a little messy under and looks good when done (right).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the sort of thing somebody might do to obscure a damaged substrate. In the ideal, then, removing that stuff without damaging anything still causes damage in a sense by exposing the old damage. I'd figure out a tolerable new layer for on top. Probably oil based primer for adhesion and to suppress bleed through, joint compound for smoothing, primer again, alkyd top coat, and cutting boards for kitchen work.